# Error occuring when trying to add search bar in activity on Action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchbar

Error occuring when trying to add search bar in activity on Action bar

**Android Manifest:**

```
    </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AllTransactions"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"

                    />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                       android:value="com.cybussolutions.wikki.afry_pay.AllTransactions" />
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                       android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
```

**Activity.java:**

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 3/11/2016.
 */
public class AllTransactions extends AppCompatActivity{
    private static final String TAG =null ;
    private List<String> items;

    private Menu menu;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_transactions);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater menuInflator=getMenuInflater();
        menuInflator.inflate(R.menu.options_menu,menu);

        SearchManager searchManager=(SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchActionbarItem=menu.findItem(R.id.search);

        SearchView searchView=(SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchActionbarItem);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        return true;

    }

    protected void handleIntent(Intent intent){
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())){
            String searchQuery=intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

        }
    }


    protected void newIntent (Intent intent){
       Log.d(TAG,"on New Intent");
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.search:
                onSearchRequested();
                return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
    }
```

Here is the Mainfest file with java code. THe Error log is below:
   Error log:

```
: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.cybussolutions.wikki.afri_pay.AllTransactions.onCreateOptionsMenu(AllTransactions.java:41)
at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2476)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:341)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:258)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1303)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1583)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:89)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:128)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I just cannot find the reason, the tutorial i followed is http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-search-in-your-apps-a-tutorial.html

what is the correct proceedure to add search bar in an activity.Waiting for you help now..

Answer (score 1):

You are missing super call in your onCreateOptionsMenu() method. It's signature looks like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And instantiate your searchview like this

```
SearchView actionSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
```

Comment: still getting the error at this line "searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));" in java activity

Comment: unable to find veriable "searchItem" .

Comment: for your question it should be searchActionbarItem

Comment: comment that searchableInfo line I don't think it is required

Comment: cross check your complete implementation with this link http://karanbalkar.com/2014/06/tutorial-84-implement-searchview-in-android/